# Please tell, can we filter data on SharePoint Hyperlink Description but not URL using sharepoint query

Tags: sharepoint-server, filter, query

Please tell is there any way or workaround we can filter on hyperlink "Description" using sharepoint query.

I know we can filter listview rendering using JSlink and hide rows but problem is when user does export to excel that again become visible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is expected behavior. When you export items into Excel via "Export to Excel", it will export all items from the saved view without JSLink.

For your requirement, you can create a new column and use it to store the URL's description, then create a view with a filter by the new column. You can create a SharePoint Designer workflow to set the new column to URL's description.

My demo workflow for your reference:
[image]

For the workflow's Start Options, you can set it like:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Kally. Appreciate your reply. As you know life is not as easy in terms of deployment and changing stuff on production. However, I have one solution for export to excel that I will handle the stuff on button by adding content editor webpart and call API for that specific view of the list and then control the rendering. However, i have marked your answer.